# Percentage Change function in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

Is there a function in pine like `pct_change()` in python,  which can calculate percentage change in pine? Since there is not data management system

Comment: There is a `change()` function but it just gives the difference between the current value and some previous value. You have to write your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`roc(source, length)`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_roc) will return 0.5 for 50%.

Answer (score 5):

So, firstly, there's the function [ta.change](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dchange), which is a difference between current value and the value n bars back in a series.
Secondly, there's also the Momentum function [ta.mom](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dmom), which is change in price specifically.
Thirdly, there is a function Rate of Change [ta.roc](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Droc), which is Momentum normalised to the price n bars back.
Fourthly, you can write your own to have said Momentum normalised to the current price if you prefer:

```
nmom = 100 * ta.mom(price, n) / price
```